# Comparing Python list values to dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new list by comparing the list items to dictionary keys, if the match is found then i append a value of dictionary to new list that was globally initialized. the code i am trying is as below

```
dict_1 = {'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24', 'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24', 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24', 'ATM': '10.1.4.0/24'}
list_1 = ['A&A', 'A&A', 'OMSS', 'OMSS', 'A&A', 'AFM', 'A&A', 'AFM', 'A&A']
list_2 = ['OMSS ', 'OMSS ', 'A&A ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ']

list_of_list1 = []

for s1 in list_1:
    #print (s2)
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        #print (key)
        if s1 == key:
            list_of_list1.append(value)

print (list_of_list1)

list_of_list2 = []

for s2 in list_2:
    #print (s2)
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        #print (key)
        if s2 == key:
            list_of_list2.append(value)

print (list_of_list2)
```

when i run this i get below output

```
['10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24']
{'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24', 'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24', 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24', 'ATM': '10.1.4.0/24'}
[]
```

i am trying to figure out why "list_of_list2" is coming out as empty?

Comment: Well, what are some differences between the strings in `list_1` and `list_2`?

Comment: It looks like there are spaces appended to values in list_2

Comment: You'll want to use `if s2.strip() == key:` (although there are simpler ways to do what you're doing, this would fix your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove leading and tailing space from the `list_2` items to be matched with the dictionary keys. Here is the sample fix of your problem:

```
dict_1 = {'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24', 'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24', 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24', 'ATM': '10.1.4.0/24'}
list_1 = ['A&A', 'A&A', 'OMSS', 'OMSS', 'A&A', 'AFM', 'A&A', 'AFM', 'A&A']
list_2 = ['OMSS ', 'OMSS ', 'A&A ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ', 'A&A ', 'AFM ']

list_of_list1 = []

for s1 in list_1:
    #print (s2)
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        #print (key)
        if s1 == key:
            list_of_list1.append(value)

print (list_of_list1)

list_of_list2 = []

for s2 in list_2:
    #print (s2)
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        #print (key)
        if s2.strip() == key:
            list_of_list2.append(value)

print (list_of_list2)
```

Output:

```
['10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24']
['10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24', '10.1.3.0/24']
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please stop using containers in most inefficient way. Just use list comprehension:

```py
list_of_list1 = [dict_1[k] for k in list_1 if k in dict_1]
```

2. All items of `list_2` have `' '` at the end. Indeed they won't be equal to the keys you have in `dict_1`. Try to strip redundant spaces:

```py
list_of_list2 = [dict_1[k.strip()] for k in list_2 if k.strip() in dict_1]
```

Comment: Thanks will try to use list comprehensions

Comment: @madbird please update the variable name of 2 from `list_of_list1` to `list_of_list2`.